# No rule to make target mbascii.c required by mbascii.o?

Tags: c, pic, mplab, pic32

I opened a project from a colleague in mplab X, it was in an archive(.zip) I added to the original path where are all my projects and I added the correct path to Harmony, but this is the  error when I build. I configured it for the correct target board and compiller and on an clean&rebuild I get the same error. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: One totally possible reason is that there *is* no rule for mbascii. We cannot tell without seeing *any* of the the rules.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but does your colleague use Windows while you use Linux?  Just had a flashback of working with someone who coded in Windows and didn't make all the includes and such case-accurate.  So his stuff compiled in the case-insensitive Windows environment but not the case-sensitive Linux environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

The project was in 1 extra folder with the same name, created when I extracted its content... I removed it, restarted the IDE, set it as main project, set the settings again for compiler and target board, run the harmony configurator, so it loaded some files and guess what... Worked like a charm... Can't believe the issue was 1 extra folder which was holding the project... Thank you for your help.

P.S: No, he was using the same OS.